# The QMainWindow's statusBar can't normally show message

Tags: qt, pyqt6

I had created a QMenu in my MainWindow class, when I tried to connect QMenu's hovered signal to a slot function which show some message in the statusBar, but it can't normally work. Here are some of my code:

```py
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        self.file_menu = QMenu("menu")
        self.file_menu.hovered.connect(lambda a: self.statusBar().showMessage(a.text()))
        self.open_action = QAction("open")
        self.file_menu.addAction(self.open_action)
        self.menuBar().addMenu(self.file_menu)
```

Comment: What does it mean "[..] but it can't normally work."?

Comment: @vahancho The meaning is that there will not be any messages displayed in the statusbar.

Comment: [`self.open_action.setStatusTip("open")`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qaction.html#statusTip-prop). Remove the hovered signal connection, as it's redundant: Qt already does that, the problem is that by default the status tip is empty, and so *clears* the status bar.